# Evaluate the limit or prove that it does not exist

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, limits, multivariable-calculus

I want to evaluate $\displaystyle \lim_{(x,y)\to (0,0)}\frac{\ln(1-x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$.

Any idea how to prove the answer is -1? I don't see an easy way to simplify this.

Comment: First of all, welcome to MSE! it is highly recommended to show some effort. Hint: Use polar coordinates - $x=r\cos(\theta),y=r\sin(\theta)$.

Comment: Anurag, the edit you suggested is not what the OP wrote. The function is $\frac{\ln(1-x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}$.

Answer (score 1):

Hint: Use the squeeze theorem and the inequality

$$\frac{-x}{1-x} \leqslant \ln(1-x) \leqslant -x$$

Answer (score 0):

Let $x=r\cos(\theta)$ and $y=r\sin(\theta)$ (polar coordinates), hence 
$$x^2+y^2=r^2\cos^2(\theta)+r^2\sin^2(\theta)=r^2$$Now,$$\lim_{(x,y)\to(0,0)}\frac{\ln(1-x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2}=\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{\ln(1-r^2)}{r^2}\underset{\text{L'Hopital}}{=}\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{-\frac{2r}{1-r^2}}{2r}=-\lim_{r\to 0}\frac{1}{1-r^2}=-1$$

Comment: Thanks! I originally tried the polar coordinates and I got as far as your second step with ln(1-r^2)/r^2 but I didn't think of using L'Hopital's rule.

Comment: Ps. Is there a good FAQ for how to use this site? I don't know how to make my math show up in a Tex format like yours.